# Using awaited with be

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

> Please be awaited for the results

Can you use past participle of verb immediately after *be* without *to*?

Sounds ok to me but I haven't heard it elsewhere.

Comment: Please await the results.  (I can't figure out how inserting "to" somewhere would fix the original.)

Comment: A person could go their whole life without ever needing to use “await”.  Please wait for the results.

Comment: "be patient" might be what you intend.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a past participle after *be*. It is the usual way of expressing the passive. If somebody **is awaiting** the results, then the results **are awaited**.

Your question suggests that you are confusing three different constructions:

A "continuous" tense (the present continuous is actually the normal present tense for most verbs):

> I am awaiting the results.

The passive:

> I am awaited.  (= somebody is awaiting me)

The infinitive of obligation (rather a formal use):

> I am to await the Director (= My duty/instructions/obligation is to await the Director).

As Jim 46 says, *await* is a formal word: in ordinary speech people would say "wait for" instead of "await" in all the above sentences.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the past participle after be; there are examples where it is desirable to do so. “Let us be seen to retreat”, “Let us be done with arguing”, “To be satisfied, I need evidence”.

But your example is not in this class. It is not the speaker who is awaited, but the results. It should read “Please await the results”.

Answer (score 0):

> *Please be awaited for the results*

I think this sentence is grammatically incorrect. I would like to suggest you one of this forms:

1. Please, let us wait for the results!
2. Please, let us await the results!
3. Let us await the results, please!
4. Would you like to let us await the results, please!
5. Would you like to let us wait for the results, please!

Comment: These all have “us” doing the waiting.  I believe OP’s intention is to direct the recipient to do the waiting. I.e., “Please wait for the results.”